# How to handle file upload from web service

Tags: java, web-services, image, upload, handler

I'm developing an Iphone/Android application.
I need to create a web service for handling uploading images.

Mobile devices can send images to my web service.

How can i handle sent files in java?

Comment: Do you mean SOAP web service?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way would be to read the image into a byte array on the client side, then send that over the web-service and convert it back into an image on the server side.